# join table on postgres with php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am still new to postgresql database , do not understand is compared with mysql . how combine 3 table in postgresql,

table1 = field_data_field_smcc_id

table2 = field_data_field_source_isolation

table3 = field_data_field_organism

```
<?php

$connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;


$link = pg_connect ($connectString);
if (!$link)
{
    die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
}

$query = 'select * from field_data_field_smcc_id';
$result = pg_query($query);


?>
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-join.html

Comment: nice thank you for answer little understood for jointable postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/joins.php).i hope meet your answer.

Comment: nice thank you for answer and how to display in html?